# Связь по HTTP протоколу

Tags: php, delphi, http

Задача состоит в том чтобы отправить данные из PHP скрипта в программу написанную на Delphi немного данных. HTTP протокол выбран так как сокеты на хостинге использовать нельзя. Пишу самый простой вариант :

```
$ip    = '000.000.000.000';
$port  = 12345;
$url   = 'http://' . $ip . ':' . $port;
echo $url;
file_get_contents( $url );
```

Программа на Delphi никак не реагирует. В ней запущен простой TIdHTTPServer. Если этот же  по этому адресу перейти из браузера, то в программке сразу срабатывают следующие события:

```
OnContextCreated
OnConnect
OnContextCreated
OnConnect
OnHeadersAvailable
OnCommandGet
OnDisconnect
OnHeadersAvailable
OnCommandGet
OnDisconnect
```

Пытаюсь получить функцией file_get_contents любой сайт – работает, а к моему ip не хочет. Если через curl вывести ошибки,то выдаёт:

```
Failed to connect to 000.000.000.000 port 12345: Connection refused
```

Та же ошибка вылазит, если даже программа-сервер вообще не включена. В чём может быть дело?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё просто. На хостинге нужно было настроить разрешённые исходящие порты.